# Error creating Haskell HTTP Request

Tags: haskell, network-programming, cabal

I am trying to create a `Request` value and am getting the following error:

```
ghci> :m +Network.HTTP Network.URI Data.Maybe
ghci> Request { rqURI = fromJust $ parseURI "http://www.google.com", rqMethod = GET, rqHeaders = [], rqBody = ""}

<interactive>:18:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `network-2.3.1.0:Network.URI.URI'
                with actual type `URI'
    In the `rqURI' field of a record
    In the expression:
      Request
        {rqURI = fromJust $ parseURI "http://www.google.com",
         rqMethod = GET, rqHeaders = [], rqBody = ""}
    In an equation for `it':
        it
          = Request
              {rqURI = fromJust $ parseURI "http://www.google.com",
               rqMethod = GET, rqHeaders = [], rqBody = ""}
```

`cabal list network` shows the following:

```
* network
    Synopsis: Low-level networking interface
    Default available version: 2.4.0.1
    Installed versions: 2.3.1.0, 2.4.0.1
    Homepage: https://github.com/haskell/network
    License:  BSD3
```

From the docs on Hackage, I believe that the URI I am creating with `parseURI` is a `Network.URI.URI`.

I am running the Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0 (64 bit) on OS X Mountain Lion.

Is this an example of "cabal hell" that I hear about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) package was built using [`network-2.3.1.0`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.3.1.0), but ghci loads the newest version of `network` unless it is explicitly told which version to use.

So `parseURI` returns a `Maybe network-2.4.0.1:Network.URI.URI` but the `Request` requires the type from `network-2.3.1.0`.

You can

- invoke ghci with a `-package` flag specifying the version of `network` to use, `$ ghci -package network-2.3.1.0 other arguments`,
- rebuild `HTTP` and everything depending on it against `network-2.4.0.1` - in that case, it's probably better to rebuild everything that transitively depends on `network-2.3.1.0`.

> Is this an example of "cabal hell" that I hear about?

I wouldn't go so far as to call that "hell" yet, but it's a small example of that indeed.

Comment: The problem appears to be that hxt-9.3.1.1 depends specifically on network-2.3.1.0. Forcing a reinstall of network will break HXT.

Comment: In that case, the `-package` flag is the way to go. Inconvenient it is, but it works.

Comment: I actually got the original error compiling an application (actually running with `runhaskell`). I copied the relevant parts to GHCi to test it further and wrote my SOF question from that. Guess I'm out-of-luck.

Comment: The `-package` flag is for GHC in general, not only ghci. If you want to compile a cabalised project, `cabal` figures out which version of `network` (in this example) gives a consistent plan and automatically chooses 2.3.1.0 (unless you use other things that depend on 2.4.0.1, in which case it'll tell you that it can't find a consistent plan). `runhaskell -package ntework-2.3.1.0 whatever` may work or not, I expect it would, but I'm not sure.